# Default value generating a UUID breaks migrations in django 1.7, is there a workaround?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Django 1.7 now requires that migrations be setup. Unfortunately, using lambdas or similar in default field values breaks this process.

I have the following in a model:

```
def make_uuid(type):
    """Takes an entity type identifier string as input and returns a hex of UUID2 with a 
    type identifier pre-pended for readability"""

    return str(type)+str(uuid.uuid1().hex)

class Accounts(models.Model):
    """Model representing Accounts"""

    PENDING_STATUS = 0
    ACTIVE_STATUS = 1
    SUSPENDED_STATUS = 2
    CANCELLED_STATUS = 3
    BETA_STATUS = 4

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (PENDING_STATUS, 'Pending'),
        (ACTIVE_STATUS, 'Active'),
        (SUSPENDED_STATUS, 'Suspended'),
        (CANCELLED_STATUS, 'Cancelled'),
        (BETA_STATUS, 'Beta'),
    )

    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    account_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=34, default=partial(make_uuid,'AC'), db_index=True, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=PENDING_STATUS)
```

The call to partial breaks the migration process with the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <functools.partial object at 0x10e5cf9f0>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
```

I still need to auto-generate the UUID, so does anyone know of a workaround to this that doesn't break migrations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that the migrations system needs to serialize the function definition, and [isn't able to do so](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#serializing-values) with the dynamically-created object returned by `partial()`.

(Note that [as of version 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#migrations) Django is in fact able to serialize `partial()` callables, and the code above would work.)

To fix this use a module-level function instead:

```
def make_uuid_ac():
    return make_uuid('AC')

class Accounts(models.Model):
    ....
    account_uuid = models.CharField(..., default=make_uuid_ac)
```

Comment: Thanks! Took me some time to really test this and be comfortable with the outcome as I was burned by the original issue, but all seems to hold up well and be rather straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass args to the function (that is for partial) there is solution in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method):

```python
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class MakeUUID(object):
    def __init__(self, pre):
        self.pre = pre

    def __call__(self, obj, *args):
        return '{}-{}-{}'.format(self.pre,
                                 obj.__class__.__name__,
                                 uuid.uuid1().hex)

make_uuid = MakeUUID('AC')
```

Also `type` as an argument name is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, but this seems a bit heavier than what I need for the moment. Answer provided by @kevin-christopher-henry solve the issue at hand with the logic I'm already comfortable with. Noted on the "type" issue.

Answer (score -1):

Re-read the documentation: ​https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

**Note that a callable (with the parentheses omitted) is passed to default, not an instance of UUID.**